# When i upload an image in the database..the last image should get deleted and new one should get saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**models.py**

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    ext2 = filename.replace(extension, "png")
    og_filename = ext2.split('.')[0]
    og_filename2 = ext2.replace(og_filename, str(instance.id))
    path =  os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/images/profile',)
    dir_list = os.listdir(path)
    for i in dir_list:
        if i == og_filename2:
            dir_list.pop(-1)
            dir_list.append(og_filename2)
            return os.path.join('profile/', og_filename2)
    return os.path.join('profile/', og_filename2)

class User(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    profile_dp = models.ImageField(upload_to = content_file_name ,null=True, blank=True)
    profile_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Through the `content_file_name()` function when i upload an image its name should change to this format `user's id.png`. and then when i again upload an image to the same field the last image should get deleted and the new image with the same name should get uploaded.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images',)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static',)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]
```